# Filling numbers in 19 cells set in a big hexagon such that....

Tags: puzzle

In social groups this question (see the photo below) of filling integers in 19 small cells set in a big hexagon is asked, such that their sum in each layer(row) in all three directions is 50. Next, it asks one to find the sum of numbers in 7 pink cells.

I named 19 unknowns row wise as $A_1,A_2,A_3; B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4; C_1, C_2,C_3,C_4, C_5; D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4; E_1, E_2, E_3$ and set up 15 linear simultaneous equations. I solved this system of consistent linear simultaneous equations at Mathematica to get values of 15 unknowns in terms of 4 of them to find that sum of numbers in pink cells: $A_1+A_3+C_1+C_3+C_5+E_1+E_3=$constant.

The question is: What is this constant and how to get it other wise?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps by symmetry you can argue that $(A_1,A_2,A_3)= (E_1,E_2,E_3)$ etc.

Comment: Okay, the constant is [$100$](https://tio.run/##LY5BDoMgEEWv0v3/mx7AOzTdGheAKKhQBZs0MZ6dEjK7P5n330xQp7NBnd6oUl7Jx7N/2/FrbH8paJiue/IxwmLC3LKDx4IVW5sCIj7YWz6QkIUZoWTva1fLPtbmJM5Ue6s4M3bxGcySdCVXMavqWCqf5RtfTUkuBRwt/bpOwSDjqOgGd/NS1DQcaTlxpqPnwpUbAyM/3HkwMd/DUMof), now we are to find the simplest linear combination)

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_hexagon will help.

Comment: Had a chance to check the link I gave, Zafar?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That page is helpfully suggestive, if you take the magic constant and compare it with the sum of cells corresponding to the pink cells in the OP, but that page concerns magic hexagons in which all cells are distinct and numbered consecutively starting from $1$, so it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Add four to each number in the outer ring, and two to each number in the inner ring, and then all the sums will be $50$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add up all six rows of length $4$, you get exactly double the blue cells (each cell is covered twice).  Hence the blue cells total $150$.  Since the entire hexagon totals $250$, the pink cells must total $100$.

Answer (score 3):

I bet the original solution will be something like this:

[image]

"The sums along blue lines minus the sums along red lines are two times the desired sum."
(Btw, the constant is now obvious, since the sum of blue lines is $50\cdot 6$ and the sum of red lines $50\cdot 2$ so the constant is $50\cdot \dfrac{6-2}{2}$)

You don't want to know how this is achieved,
in short, yes, the linear system $Ax=b$, then $yA^T=t$ (where $t$ consists of $1$ for target (pink) variables, $0$ for others) feeds to WA, WA produces $3$ free variables solution ($y$) and we minimize the number of non-$0$ coefficients.
the python source:

```
from sympy import *
import itertools
from functools import reduce
import re
R=Rational
transitions=[(1,2),(2,0)]
t1=set((a*i,b*j) for i,j in transitions
    for a,b in itertools.product([-1,1],repeat=2))
assert len(t1)==6
t2=set((a+b,c+d) for (a,c),(b,d) in itertools.product(t1,repeat=2))
assert len(t1|t2)==19
_all=sorted(t1|t2,key=lambda x:x[::-1])
coords=[(R(i),j*sqrt(R(3))/R(2)) for i,j in _all]
_dict={i:n for n,i in enumerate(coords)}
cut=lambda l,c:reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+[x[1][:y]],x[1][y:]),c,([],l))[0]
rot=[[(a*i+b*j,-b*i+a*j) for i,j in coords] for a,b in
     [(R(1),R(0)),(R(1,2),sqrt(R(3))/R(2)),(R(1,2),-sqrt(R(3))/R(2))]]
assert all(j in _dict for i in rot for j in i)
_n=[[_dict[k] for k in j] for i in rot for j in cut(i,[3,4,5,4,3])]
target=[0,2,18-0,18-2,9,9+2,9-2]
_m=[[[0,1][j in i] for j in range(19)] for i in _n+[target]]
_l=''.join(chr(ord('a')+n) for n,i in enumerate(_m))
#print(', '.join('%s == 1'%(' + '.join(_l[j] for j in i)) for i in _n))
#at this point we simply feed the output into WA, producing the result in s
print(', '.join('%s == %d'%(' + '.join(
    _l[n] for n,j in enumerate(i[:-1]) if j),i[-1])
                for i in zip(*_m)))
s=r'''c == 1 - a + 2*b && d == 1 - 2*a + 3*b && e == 2 - 3*a + 4*b && g == -1 + a - b + f && h == -1 + 2*a - 2*b + f && i == -2 + 3*a - 3*b + f && j == -2 + 4*a - 4*b + f && k == 2 - 3*a + 2*b - f && l == 1 - 2*a + b - f && m == 1 - a - f && n == -b - f && o == a - 2*b - f'''
s=list(zip(*(i.split(' == ') for i in s.split(' && '))))
matcher=re.compile(r'\d+')
s,_v='(%s)'%(', '.join(matcher.sub((lambda m:'R(%s)'%(m.group(0))),i)
                       for i in s[1])),s[0]
_f=lambda a,b,f:eval(s)
x=min(
#i for i in
itertools.product([R(j,12) for j in range(-24,25)],repeat=3),
key=lambda i:sum(j!=R(0) for j in _f(*i)+i)
)
print(x,_f(*x))
#print(
assert all(
    [(sum(_m[_l.index(v)][k]*j
        for j,v in zip(x+_f(*x),('a','b','f')+_v))
     ==_m[-1][k])
      for k in range(19)]
)
for j,v in zip(x+_f(*x),('a','b','f')+_v):
    if j!=0:
        print(j,_n[_l.index(v)])
```

Comment: P.S. Seems the problem is taken from [here](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/hexagon-puzzle).

Comment: Please mentionl the constant you get. Good that you found the source.

Comment: Please mention it ithere for the uninitiated readers, it helps.